# Getting ClassNotFoundException when running Robolectric tests with the Maven surefire plugin

Tags: android, maven, robolectric

I've set up a project in Eclipse using the Android Maven integration, and Robolectric for some tests.

The tests run fine when I deploy them in Eclipse. However, when I try to build the project with the **Maven "install" goal** (this is actually a library that I need in my local Maven repository), it fails on these same tests.

Logs show the following error:

```
testAll((package).MyTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while obtaining a class file for (package).R
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:316)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setupApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:270)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:221)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:201)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while obtaining a class file for (package).R
    at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:359)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.findClass(RobolectricClassLoader.java:60)
    at javassist.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:311)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.loadClass(RobolectricClassLoader.java:37)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:312)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.IgnorableClassNotFoundException: msg because of javassist.NotFoundException: (package).R
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.AndroidTranslator.onLoad(AndroidTranslator.java:80)
    at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:340)
    ... 29 more
```

where (package) is of course the name of my main package. Here's the relevant section of my POM:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
   <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
        <configuration>
        <genDirectory>${project.basedir}/gen</genDirectory>
          <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
          <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
          <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
          <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
          <sdk>
            <platform>7</platform>
          </sdk>
          <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
          <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>      
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

As you can see, I've tried adding the "genDirectory" option to the Maven Android plugin. But to no avail.

What am I missing to make the surefire plugin "see" the R class?

One more thing: the R class is not actually referenced by my code.

Comment: What do you mean an "install" goal?  Eclipse has Run and Debug modes for executing applications.  Installation is handled by the Android SDK.  If you're getting errors specifically from the Maven/Robolectric code, make sure you're including them in your build path.

Comment: The "install" goal is a Maven-specific action - it adds your project to your local Maven repository (this project is actually a library). In other words - this is something independent from the Eclipse run cycle. I'll edit my question to be clearer in this respect.

Comment: The R.java class is compiled by Android - you should not be referencing it outside of an Android project, specifically, you CANNOT reference it without an activity reference.

Comment: That's true, but like I've said previously, I am using the Android plugin for Maven, which is specifically designed to build and deploy Android applications, so that shouldn't be a problem. See here for more info:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ .

To clarify it a bit further (and apologies if you know this) - Maven is not actually a library, but a build system, something like Ant for example.

Also - I'm not actually referencing R, it looks like Roboelectic does that. Obviously I have something wrong with my Maven config, but I don't know what - hence the question.

Comment: I would try looking directly into the .classpath generated files and seeing if R.java is referenced anywhere in there.  That may be your first clue as to how to fix this :)

Comment: I'm afraid that, as far as I know, Maven is agnostic about the .classpath file as well, even when run through the Eclipse plugin - but thanks for your help :).

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I am getting the same exception when running JUnit in Eclipse, after I upgrade m2e and m2e android eclipse plugin.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. I plan to get back to that during this week, update the plugins, update the Maven deps, and if that fails, I'll ask on the Robolectric group.

I suggest that if any one of us succeeds, we should post the answer here, for posterity ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem when trying to run a test from Eclipse, first time after adding Robolectric.

What solved the problem for me was `mvn clean test` on the command line.
After that, the test ran OK from Eclipse as well.

And make sure you have `<packaging>apk</packaging>` in your pom.xml.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. If that's not too big of a problem, could you edit in your POM? Maybe I have something misconfigured...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this is actually a library". I have `<packaging>apk</packaging>` in my pom. If I replace it with `<packaging>jar</packaging>` then it fails with "package R does not exist".

Comment: ...and of course that worked (I wanted to make the usage a bit more convenient until I set up a Maven repo, and that backfired). Thanks!

Could you add the info to set the packaging to "apk", so that I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: One more thing - since 3.0.0 of android-maven-plugin (yes, the name has changed) you can use the "apklib" target. This is what I actually needed :).

Answer (score 4):

I also got exactly this issue.

So I compared carefully between RobolectricSample project and my project.

To my surprise, the RobolectricSample project also could NOT work if I didn't run the command line of "mvn clean test" first.

Therefore I analysed the difference and found that the command line compiled the "gen/xxx/R.java" to "target/classes/xxx/R" too.

That's the trick of success so I did the following steps:
1. right click project -> Java Build;
2. change the "{project}/gen" output folder as "target/class" (instead of original "target/android-classes")

That's it and hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the only way to fix this issue was to place a fake R.java file into the package:

```
    public class R {
        public static final class attr {
        }

        public static final class drawable {
        }

        public static final class id {
        }

        public static final class layout {
        }

        public static final class string {
        }
    }
```

This should only be necessary under the following circumstances:

1. Maven library project
2. unit test dependencies on Robolectric
3. R.java not being generated or not found on maven classpath.

Note:  You can put R.java in your test sources so that it isn't deployed.  This won't then interfere with actual resources created.

Comment: Yeah this is what i did to keep my packaging type as a jar

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when running Robolectric tests both in eclipse and on the command line via `mvn clean test`.  I.e. a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` complaining that my R.class file was not found.  Indeed, there was no R.class file since my project is an Android library that has no resources.

A *dirty hack* to get rid of the error is to create a `<project-home>/res/values/strings.xml` file with a single unused string. Then the R.java and the corresponding R.class are generated and the error goes away.