# TypeNotPresentException when running android testcase with robolectric and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, robolectric

I've the following example test case set up set up in an android test project I'm working on.

```
package com.whatever.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

  @Test
  public void testFromJson() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
  }

}
```

I did set up a junit run configuration, it runs with junit4 and I've tried both with Java 6 (mac os x default) and oracle's jdk 7.

No matter how I try I always get the following error

```
    java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner not present
at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:28)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:57)
at $Proxy4.value(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:95)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:107)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:370)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:351)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:280)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3070)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3029)
at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:13)
... 12 more
```

I'm using last android sdk (api level 17) bundled in the adt package and I'm using robolectric 1.1 as an external JAR.

I'm open to alternatives if running the tests with eclipse in that way is not the best.

**Edit**: I've been suggested to check that Robolectric appears before Android in the classpath, which I did. And the problem persists.

**Edit 2**: I've followed the suggestions in the comments, but none of them seemed to work, the error persists.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's going wrong.  It looks like there is a configuration error, can you provide more information about how it's imported into eclipse?  It looks like you're getting a `ClassNotFound` when trying to run it.  I had an issue were JUnit4 had to be imported before android.  That's something to check.  Take a look at: http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html Make sure you followed the instructions.  Try creating a new project and get that working, then figure out what's different between that one and yours.

Comment: Sound like a classpath problem, try using [robolectric-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~robolectric), you may also need harmcrest.jar and maps.jar.

Comment: I've tried both options and none of them worked. I'm afraid that there's something more that I'm doing wrong but I can't find what is it.

Comment: How's the project located compared to the target project? Roboletric needs access to your manifest etc. By default it assumes a flat structure Iirc. You can extend the testrunner to change the path. You'll need an XML file or something resources too

Comment: MrChaz, I tried all those too without any success, I'm just trying to. I'm going to follow in the path of the selected answer and investigate a bit more. Thank you all for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen these two discussions:

[Getting ClassNotFoundException when running Robolectric tests with the Maven surefire plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082698/getting-classnotfoundexception-when-running-robolectric-tests-with-the-maven-sur)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/robolectric/6c8WmE-qjlk